# Effects of only drinking soda (no water)

Tags: physical-health, hydration

I have several college friends who never drink water - only soda. Water is too bland for them. What are the long term effects of this lifestyle?

Comment: Please at least mention some of the prior research you have done on the subject.

Comment: In addition to what user1271772 correctly mentions, questions about nutrition that are not specifically about medical treatment are [not appropriate for this site](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [this Meta discussion](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-sort-of-nutrition-or-environmental-questions-are-suitable-now/) for more information. At this time, there are [*no* Stack Exchange communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375543/is-there-a-community-about-nutrition) where this type of question is well suited.

Comment: If you can otherwise edit your question to become on-topic, be sure to define exactly what you mean by "soda". For example in the UK it would mean carbonated water, the US it covers any number of beverages with a huge diversity of ingredients from sugar through artificial sweeteners, caffeine and an astonishing variety of other stimulants, preservatives, flavours and colours  with a variety of faddy-additives emerging onto the market all the time.